# ¿Cómo recupero el último id insertado en una consulta mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    
    $a = $_POST['name'];
    $b = $_POST['lastname'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO prueba(p1,p2) VALUES('$a','$b')";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($query){
        $ultimo_id = mysql_insert_id(); 
        echo" $ultimo_id";
        
        echo"exitos";
    }

}
```

Lo tengo de esta manera pero me arroja error, la tabla ya es AI.
Quiero recuperar ese id para volver a hacer otra consulta y agregar ese mismo id en mi otra tabla para que tenga relación.

Comment: Que error te arroja?

Comment: Lo que te puede estar sucediendo que estas utilizando mysql_insert_id(); cuando deberias utilizar mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_insert_id() in C:\xampp\htdocs\start\prueba.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\start\prueba.php on line 11.

Comment: mysqli_insert_id($conexion); , no no funciona me arroja el mismo error. de que otra fuerma puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Primero, valide los envíos del formulario. Al menos que existan los dos valores (Debe realizar más validaciones para evitar problemas con de xss). Después, valide que la sentencia sea correcta con el primer `if`.
Luego valide si existen resultados, con el segundo `if`.
Si todo va bien, utilice la función para obtener el id registrado y asigne la conexión: `mysqli_insert_id($con);`

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])){
    $a = $_POST['name'];
    $b = $_POST['lastname'];
    if (mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO prueba(p1,p2) VALUES ('$a','$b')")) {
       if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)){
          $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
       } else {
          echo "No se insertó";
       }
    } else {
        echo "error query";
    }
}
```